# Workbox not recognizing root url regex /^\/$/ added to navigation fallback blacklist

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have a SPA with service worker generated with Workbox webpack plugin. The root url "/" is a separate home page for my website and not part of my SPA, so I want my service worker to not fallback to the app shell of my SPA but instead fetch the home page from server when I navigate to "/". I know workbox has the navigationFallbackBlacklist option to specify url patterns that are not a part of the SPA. This option is working for several other url paths that my website have but not the root url. I am wondering if there are some work arounds for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Working for mi:
With workbox-build and generateSw:

```
    ...
       runtimeCaching: [
        {
            urlPattern: /^https:\/\/(www\.)?test.local(\/)?$/,
            handler: 'NetworkFirst', 
            options: {
                cacheName: 'home-page',
                expiration: {
                    maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 DAYS
                    maxEntries: 1
                }
            }
        },
```

Or writing manually:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /^https:\/\/(www\.)?test.local(\/)?$/,
    workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
        cacheName: 'home-page',
        ...
    })
)
(NetworkFirst handler mode is important, in many cases)
```